# How to retrieve confidence scores for pose landmarks?

Tags: mediapipe

I'm applying MediaPipe Holistic to scenes that can be challenging to parse.

I would like to retrieve in Python the computed confidence score for each landmark returned by MediaPipe's pose model. After a few hours of searching the answer seems to be "you can't get there from here":

https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/3104

Has anyone found a solution?

Yours truly,

Ronnen.